# python to SQL loading csv files giving error "must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to execute sql statement using python, returns an error.

I am basically trying to insert multiple csv records from a folder in sql.
I would like to insert csv records row by row in sql without making a data frame.
I have made a variable that has a string which contains sql statement. I  use that variable in execute function. like this - 
`cur1.execute(sql_query, row)`

```
import os
import csv
import pyodbc
import time

conn1 = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};'
                       r'Server=Servername;'
                       r'Database=Testing;'
                       r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cur1 = conn1.cursor()

start = time.time()
sql_query ='INSERT INTO testing01( EmployeeID'\
           ',EmployeeName'\
           ',ProjectID'\
           ',WBSElement'\
           ',StartDate'\
           ',EndDate'\
           ',AbsenceAttendanceHours'\
           ',AllocationPercent'\
           ',CRMID'\
           ',PCMTID'\
           ',ProjectPracticeID' \
           ',ProjectSBU' \
           ',SBUAbbrivation' \
           ',ProjSBUName' \
           ',ProjectPractice'\
           ',EmployeeSBU' \
           ',EmployeePractice' \
           ',EmployeeSubPractice' \
           ',ProjectProfile' \
           ',ProjectReason' \
           ',BillType' \
           ',SubBillType'\
           ',CustomerName'\
           ',ProjectManagerID'\
           ',ProjectManager'\
           ',DeliveryManagerID' \
           ',DeliveryManager' \
           ',SupervisorID' \
           ',Supervisor'\
           ',RoleSite'\
           ',RoleID' \
           ',C' \
           ',ActivityType' \
           ',RoleStatus' \
           ',CountryName' \
           ',EmployeeGrade' \
           ',JoiningDate' \
           ',ResourceGroup'\
           ',PersonnelArea' \
           ',PersonnelSubArea' \
           ',CustomerSite' \
           ',LastWorkingDayDate' \
           ',NameofEEsubgroup'\
           ',RoleName'\
           ',StreamName'\
           ',SkillName'\
           ',SkillGroup'\
           ',PrimarySkill'\
           ',Billability'\
           ',AmtInLocCur'\
           ',Currency'\
           ',RoleFTE'\
           ',OffshoreAmount'\
           ',OnsiteAmount'\
           ',EmployeeStatus'\
           ',BusinessLead'\
           ',BusinessLeadName)' 'values(?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?,?'\
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?,?,?' \
           '?,?,?,?)'

for files in os.listdir("C://Users/XXX/Desktop/ABC/ZCP/"):
    print(files)
    with open("C://Users/XXX/Desktop/ABC/ZCP/" + files, "r") as file:
        readercsv = csv.reader(file)
        next(readercsv)
        for row in readercsv:
            cur1.execute(sql_query, row)

            conn1.commit()
print("success attrition")


end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

I want to know the necessary changes to get this working.
The error I get is :

```
cur1.execute(sql_query, row)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@P6@P7". (137) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not separating `?` passed between newlines with a comma, e.g.:

```
'values(?,?,?,?,?,?' \ 
       '?,?,?,?,?,?,?'\
```

Not when the first line and the second line get concatenated, they will form a string like so:

```
 values(?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?
# note            ^^
```

So you'll need to make sure to add a comma after the trailing `?` in each line, except for the last.